# How to display FontAwesome icons in react HTML set with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I have a react.js web app and a REST API that returns a chunk of raw HTML (not a complete page). I get the HTML by scrapping a website and grabbing a piece of the markup using cherrio.js. In the developer tools, the response itself is the markup. I use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlMarkup }} element attribute so that react knows to display it as the inner HTML.

However, I need to insert some FontAwesome icons into it. I've tried both straight HTML using, `<i class="fa-solid fa-star-sharp"></i>`, and the react version, `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-star-sharp" />`. Both of these come straight from the FA docs.

Within my component that inserts the HTML I import the FontAwesomeIcon component (import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";) and also import the FontAwesome CDN CSS file using a SASS file that I import into my root JS file. I also import the @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css file.

SASS file: fa.scss
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/fontawesome.min.css);

index.js
import 'fa.scss';

However, after I load the HTML markup, insert my icon, and then set the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute, my icon doesn't display.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle? It's hard to understand the situation without a code to look at

Comment: I don't think using the `<FontAwesomeIcon />` component inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML will work. And I believe the default behaviour of `<i class="fa-solid fa-star-sharp"></i>` is to show the icon using webfonts. Is it possible for you to "create a kit" on the fontawesome website and load the webfont using the script tag in your html?

Comment: I have created a sample app on github that shows the behavior. The markup being inserted is the actual markup for today at my location (zipcode 84325). Here is the link: https://github.com/flyfisher1952/basic-example. my latest attempt is to put the CDN link into the index.html file in /public and use the <I> syntax. I'm scrapping from https://solunarforecast.com/hunting_fishing/best_times/zip_postal_code/calendar/us/84325.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using react-icons. I cheated by adding the icon I wanted to a regular page, inspecting the HTML element in Chrome dev tools, and copying the SVG that react-icons generates for the icon into a string in my code. I then replace the icon used in the markup with the SVG markup.

Works like a charm.

There is also a way to programmatically add the required FontAwesome CSS file into the markup as a react element which also worked. But once I saw that react-icons had everything I needed and is free, I switched over.